# When solving a simultaneous equation like this:

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, factoring

When solving a simultaneous equation like this:

$2y - x = 4 $

$2x² + 3y² = x + 4y = 17 $

How do you express this second equation? I know how to solve simultaneous equations. I'm not just sure of how to express it.

Attempt: 
I solved it in two ways. I made it in this form:

$2x² + 3y² - x - 4y = 17 $

And then solved it. It became a quadratic equation and I got two values for x and y which when I replaced gave me the equation back. I'm not just sure that's how to express it.

I also solved it by separating the second equation into two different equations

$2x² + 3y² = 17 $

$x + 4y = 17 $

Which when I solved didn't equate when I replaced it.

So how is it supposed to be? Thanks

Comment: Your second equation has two ='s. Is that a typo?

Comment: No it is not a typo. That's what is confusing about the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in fact three equations and two unknowns, so there is a possibility that the system has no solution. To find out, we choose the two easier (independent) equations and check the solution in the third.
$$
\cases{
2y-x=4,\\
4y+x=17,}
$$
implying that $6y=21$, so $y=7/2$ and $x=3$. To check the third equation:
$$2\cdot3^2+3(7/2)^2=\frac{219}4\neq17$$
So the system has *no solution*.

Comment: Thank you very much. So it was wrong for me to express it in this form right? $2x² + 3y² - x - 4y = 17 $

Comment: You are welcome. Yes. That was wrong. it would be correct to write $2x^2+3y^2-x-4y=0$ though.

Answer (score 1):

From $2x^2+3y^2=x+4y=17$ I deduce that $2x^2+3y^2=17$ as well as $x+4y=17$ You can simply graph to see that the ellipse and the line do not intersect...